# Is there a way to prevent the compiler from putting a constexpr function into the object file?

Tags: c++

I have a constexpr function that I don't want to show up in the binary. Only the result should be in there, computed at compile time. Is this possible?

Edit:
The question came up when I looked at the output of this piece of code and discovered that the binary didn't change in size, whether or not I made the variable `constexpr` in main. Compiled using mingw `g++ -std=c++17 -O2`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <std::size_t I>
constexpr auto fizzbuzz_elem()
{
    if constexpr (I % 5 == 0 && I % 3 == 0) {
        return "FizzBuzz";
    } else if constexpr (I % 5 == 0) {
        return "Buzz";
    } else if constexpr (I % 3 == 0){
        return "Fizz";
    } else {
        return I;
    }
}

template <std::size_t...Is>
constexpr auto fizzbuzz_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
    return std::make_tuple(fizzbuzz_elem<1 + Is>()...);
}

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto fizzbuzz(){
    return fizzbuzz_impl(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main() {
    auto res = fizzbuzz<42>();
    std::apply([](auto... e){ ((std::cout << e << std::endl), ...); }, res);
}
```

Comment: What platform and compiler are you using?

Comment: Have you tested to see what shows up in the binary using a trivial test program?

Comment: g++ with -std=c++17 in mingw

Comment: Which optimization flag did you use?

Comment: You can't force constexpr functions to be at compile time unless what is using it is also a compile time thing.  This was "fixed" in C++20 with the introduction of consteval functions.

Comment: Edited my question for more concreteness. I thought constexpr was great for reducing binary size, but it isn't?

Comment: @Skusku Question is much improved from last time. Why is the binary size a concern, typically `constexpr` is used to improve runtime performance?

Comment: @M.A Thanks. If I can have both, I'd take both. I have embedded systems in mind with small amounts of flash. Being able to create look up tables at compile time and throw away all the unnecessary template functions would be a charm.

Comment: @Skusku  yep, code bloat is an issue with templates. You can optimise for size (`-Os`) but I assume you are aware of this.

Comment: @Skusku Try declaring it with internal linkage (declare it `static` or anonymous namespace), and make sure it isn't called outside of constant contexts. I didn't test if this would work.

Comment: @eerorika No change unfortunately!

Comment: @M.A No change here either.

Comment: `[[gnu::always_inline]] template <...> inline constexpr auto ...`. Or wait until C++20 and use `consteval`.